# SQL join and count do net get it together

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'am a beginner in SQL and have some trouble with joining and counting at the same time.
First let me explain my two tables.
I have the following:

```
   Table: AnalysePageview
          id       title     session      more
        -----------------------------------------------------
           1         a           10        0
           2         b           20        1
           3         c           30        1            
           4         d           40        1
           5         e           50        1
           6         f           60        0

    Table: AnalyseEvent
          id       name     session      more
        -----------------------------------------------------
           1         a           10        0
           2         b           10        1
           3         c           10        1            
           4         d           20        1
```

and I would like to join this two and add a line like this:

```
    New Table:
          id       name       session   counts (out off AnalyseEvent)
        -----------------------------------------------------
           1         a           10        3
           2         b           20        1
           3         c           30        0            
           4         d           40        0
           5         e           50        0
           6         f           60        0
```

I just tried this:

```
SELECT *, 
       COUNT( AnalyseEvent.session ) AS totalViews 
FROM AnalysePageview  
LEFT JOIN AnalyseEvent ON AnalysePageview.session = AnalyseEvent.session
```

thanks for any help in advance. (my be with a small beginner explanation)

Comment: In your questions you should also state whats wrong with your attempt. Just makes it easier for people to identify the problem and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `group by`:

```
SELECT apv.id, apv.name, apv.session, COUNT( ae.session ) AS totalViews
FROM AnalysePageview  apv LEFT JOIN
     AnalyseEvent ae
     ON apv.session = ae.session
GROUP BY apv.id, apv.name, apv.session;
```

I also added table aliases to make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: why to group over all (apv.id, apv.name, apv.session) isn't apv.session enought?

Comment: @hamburger : because it is not clear what to do with all `n` different values in column `apv.name` (for example) for the same `apv.session` in case you group by this only column, so you should either apply aggregate functions to the fields that are contained in the `SELECT` clause and not contained in the `GROUP BY` clause or put them in the `GROUP BY` clause, it depends on the desired result, of course, as it would be different for the two approaches above in general case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by. Something like:

```
select apw.id, apw.title, apw.session, count(1)
from AnalysePageview apw
left join AnalyseEvent ae
    on apw.session = ae.session
group by apw.id, apw.title, apw.session
```

Comment: It's a bit complicated. SQL92 mandates that a full group by is used, SQL99 loosens this and demands that all columns in select is functionally dependent of the group by clause. AFAIK all DBMS uses the stricter SQL92 definition, mysql ignores it completely and produces a random result unless one overrides the default setting. If tat is the case, mysql also uses the stricter definition. If you know that the other columns are f.d. of apw.session you can apply an aggregate function such as max on the others.